# Delphi IDE: Keyboard shortcut to duplicate current line or selection?

Tags: delphi

Many even simple editors (e.g. Notepad++ or RubyMine) have this: pressing Ctrl+D duplicates the current selection or the current line if nothing is selected.

Is there any shortcut like that in the Delphi IDE (2010 or XE2)? I read through the various short cut lists, but didn't find anything.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a shortcut for this in Delphi IDE.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to write an add-in to effect that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en)  plugin has this feature (Ctrl+Alt+D).

Comment: Notepad++ implements it a little bit better: It places the cursor not at the end of the newly inserted line but at the same column. But CnPack's way to do is better than nothing and leaves the clipboard untouched.